# I can't get the most basic calc-mode gnuplot example to work

Tags: calc

I would like to graph functions and datasets from calc-mode. (That's a reasonable thing to do in 2021, right?)

Following the directions at [Basic Graphics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Basic-Graphics) and [Vectors as Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#List-Tutorial), I started calc-mode, created two vectors, and typed `g f`:

```
--- Emacs Calculator Mode ---
2: [0, 1, 2, 3]
1: [0, 1, 3, 9]
   .
g f
```

No graph is produced. In the `*Gnuplot Trail*` buffer that is created, I can see that I've got gnuplot v5.4 installed.

(BTW, TIL that the 'gnu' in 'gnuplot' has nothing to do with 'GNU', [How did it come about and why is it called gnuplot?](http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/index.html#x1-70001.2))

Also in the trail buffer, there are these error messages:

```
Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> 
Terminal type is now 'unknown'
                      ^
         unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list

gnuplot> gnuplot> 
gnuplot> set notime
               ^
         "/var/folders/cj/hmr0n_q91kd7lg4jsqb8w9100000gn/T/calcAkJV7MZ" line 23: Unrecognized option.  See 'help unset'.
```

This makes me think I am using too new a version of gnuplot for the version of Calc I have installed. I am running vanilla Emacs 27.1. I couldn't figure out how to get Calc to tell me what version of calc-mode I have installed (including reading the source).

Searching `site:emacs.stackexchange.com calc-mode gnuplot` produced nothing of relevance.

I have once gotten the contents of various buffers like `*Gnuplot Temp*`, `*Gnuplot Temp-2*`, and `*Gnuplot Commands*`, saved them into independent local files, and run `gnuplot` from the command line and gotten a chart created, but I would like to figure out how to get things to work the normal way.

What should I do next?

Comment: Try `g D default` and `g f` again.

Comment: That didn't seem to result in any difference. (Hi again NickD!)

Comment: But then I tried `g D qt`, and THAT got `g f` to work. Now I will try to figure out how to set that terminal type as my default, to see if that results in calc graphing without further twiddling

Comment: `C-u g D qt` should set it permanently according to the doc.

Comment: The other thing I needed to do was edit the source code to replace 'set notime' with 'unset timestamp'. I can't figure any way around needing to do that. I guess I will try to figure out how to ask if I should submit a PR for that?

Comment: Apparently `set notimestamp` is OK - see the [fix](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=78017a6e598ed7663aa04bd19c426f16bbc05006)

Comment: Interesting, even just adding an `s` to `time` appears sufficient. Followup question tho. That fix went in on 2020-12-07. The [latest version of 27.1.91](https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/emacs-27.1.91.tar.xz) came out on 2021-01-29, but still lacks the commit that fixes this problem. How can I tell which version of Emacs will have this fix in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got the same issue here (emacs 27.1 and gnuplot 5.4).
Calc is issuing an option which is unknown to gnuplot: `set notime`. This seems to be a bug in calc. Calc is also issuing multiple deprecated commands (it should use `unset` instead of `set no...`), but these only trigger warnings.

To work around the unknown option, locate file `calc-graph.el` and edit it. In this file search for the string `set notime\n` and replace it with `set notimestamp\n`.

It is at line 354:

```
         "set notime\nset border\nset ztics\nset zeroaxis\n"
```

this line needs to state:

```
         "set notimestamp\nset border\nset ztics\nset zeroaxis\n"
```

Save the file (maybe compile it) and restart Emacs.

Afterwards plotting is working again.

**Edit**. this is already fixed in recent version at github.com/emacs-mirror.
**Edit2:** NickD posted the [link to the fixing commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=78017a6e598ed7663aa04bd19c426f16bbc05006)